# RabbitMQ configuration version control best practices

Tags: git, version-control, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ. I configure exchanges, queues and bindings from the web client (GUI). I plan to have many udrelated exchanges and queues in the cluster. I would like to have all the configurations under version control - preferably git.

After searching web I discovered that i can use `rabbitmqadmin export_definitions` to export all definitions from RabbiMQ into a `json` file. I can keep this file under version control in git.

The disadvantage is that this way I have everything on one pile without any segmentation. Furthermore `json` format does not suport any comments.

Are there any best practices how to keep configuration documented and under version control or how do you handle this problem?